# How do I compare two strings in a template file?

Tags: theming

The template file I am using contains the following code.

```
foo is '{{ foo }}'
item.url is '{{ item.url }}'
{% if item.url == foo %}
  equal
{% endif %}
```

I was expecting this code to output *foo is 'test' item.url is 'test' equal*, but instead it outputs *foo is 'test' item.url is 'test'*; the *equal* part doesn't appear.

The following code works.

```
{% if 'test' == 'test' %}
```

This code doesn't work.

```
{% if item.url == 'test' %}
```

Why doesn't the code I am using work?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on the context, but most likely `item.url` is not a native string variable `test`, but a function or a render array with the string representation / render result `test`.

This is similar to Drupal's well known `content` variable: When you render `{{ content }}`, you will get the string representation like `<div class="something">content...</div>`. But when you do a `dump` or `kint`, you will see that content is an array, and doing a comparision `{% if content = '<div class="something">content...</div>' %}` will be false too.

I'd recommend to always avoid boolean operations with rendered representations, always head for the raw data. E.g. don't do `{% if content.field_something.0 == 'my_value' %}`, instead inspect the entity `{% if node.field_something.0.value == 'my_value' %}`.

If you have to compare to a render array, you could do somehting like `{% if some_var|render == 'my_string' %}`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help.  Adding |render works great.